# time complexity of inserting n number of nodes into an empty height balanced binary search tree using recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search-tree

I would like to know:

- what would be the worst case time complexity of inserting n number of nodes into an empty height balanced binary search tree using recursion?

I know that the worst case time complexity of inserting one node into a balanced BST is O(logn). but I am confused as to whether its the same case when I insert node into an empty balanced BST.

Comment: You should only ask one question. Also show your research efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert into an empty tree would would initialize a root pointer and a data node.  This would be constant time operation.